# Pandas updating changes to appended values that are modified afterwards

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas

I have a code where I open a spreadsheet, read it, and save it in a multidimensional array and look for string matches.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = pd.ExcelFile("File.xlsx")

top100 = []
pub = []
ind = []
missed = []

for i in range(len(file.sheet_names)):
    year = 2005 + i
    df_aux = pd.read_excel(file, str(year))
    top100.append(df_aux)
    df_aux2 = pd.read_excel("AnotherFile"+str(year+".xls")
    pub.append(df_aux2)
    ind_aux = []
    missed_aux = []
    df_aux2['Contributors'] = df_aux2['Contributors'].str.replace(" ",'')
    df_aux['Institution'] = df_aux['Institution'].str.replace(" ",'')    
    for j in range(len(df_aux2)):
        a = np.where(df_aux2['Contributors'][j] == df_aux['Institution'])[0]
        if len(a)>0:
            ind_aux.append(j)
        else:
            missed_aux.append(j)
    ind.append(ind_aux)
    missed.append(missed_aux)
```

The purpose of the code is to find the matches on the lists. Because they are strings and have some issues, I delete all blank spaces. My understanding is that that shouldn't change what was already been appended, but if I print for example pub[0] I get all the words without spaces.

```
print(pub[0]['Contributors'])
"Therearenospaces"
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Celius Stingher response, the following worked:

```
new_pub = pub.copy()
```

Comment: Will edit my answer to contemplate this case, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens because with `pub.append(df_aux2)`, you don't actually have two different values. The assignment just copies the reference to a value, not the actual dataframe, so both the appended `df_aux2` and the formal `df_aux2` refer to the same variable after the assignment.
To actually copy a list, you can use `list.copy()` method, which is available since Python 3.3 I believe. If I a not mistaken, this should do the trick:

```
new_pub = pub.append(df_aux2).copy()
```

Comment: Where in the code should I put it? I tried replacing `pub.append(df_aux2)` but I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'`